# Common rules in calculating angles of diagonal lines in quadrangle, using synthetic(axiomatic) geometry.

Tags: angle, axiomatic-geometry

[image]

In this quadrangle, if $x, y, a, b$ is determined,

$c$ has to be determined too.

Can $c$ be expressed using $x, y, a, b$?

Searching similar questions in axiomatic geometry is hard.

If similar question is present, please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: there are several triangles whose angles are all known.

Comment: @dxiv I have tried making a triangle EBC (E is a new dot that makes EBC a triangle, which is at the upper side of ABCD)
Can you be more specific about the hint?

Comment: Let $\,BC=d\,$, then you can calculate all sides and diagonals in terms of $\,d\,$ and the given angles, then you can solve one of the triangles for the $\,c\,$ angle.

Comment: @dxiv I assume letting $BC=d$ is not pure axiomatic geometry...? If you could hint or answer with drawings, that would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*pure axiomatic geometry*". The answer for $\,c\,$ is going to involve the law of sines/cosines and trig functions. To start, you could calculate $AB$ from triangle $ABC$ where you know one side $BC=d$ and all angles. Then look for another measure that you can calculate in triangle $ABD$ which, together with angle $\,y\,$, would allow finding $\,c\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your explanation, now I know that only in special circumstances, $c $ can be calculated without using the law of sines/cosines and trig functions.
I posted a new question related to this
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230763/calculating-angles-of-diagonal-lines-in-quadrangle-using-axiomatic-geometry