# Calculating angles of diagonal lines in quadrangle, using axiomatic geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, axiomatic-geometry

In my previous question: [Common rules in calculating angles of diagonal lines in quadrangle, using synthetic(axiomatic) geometry.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230038/common-rules-in-calculating-angles-of-diagonal-lines-in-quadrangle-using-synthe)

I wanted to know the common rule for calculating angles of diagonal lines in quadrangle only with axiomatic geometry,
but I realized that only in special circumstances the angle can be calculated without involving the law of sines/cosines and trig functions.

The original question was.

[image]

and the unknown source of the answer is

[image]

My first question was in the original question, but it turned out there is no common rule.

The second question is, is there any other solution for this problem?
I know that answers for axiomatic geometry problems can be ridiculous, but this is beyond imagination. (Or is this a well-known trick?)